# Function.prototype.call alters typeof this, outside strict mode; why?

Tags: javascript, function, call, strict, strict-mode

```
var example = function () {
  console.log(typeof this);
  return this;
};
```

In strict mode: `example.call('test') # prints 'string'`

Otherwise, `example.call('test') # prints 'object'`

However, `console.log(example.call('test'))` prints `test` (as you'd expect)

Why does `Function.call` change `typeof 'test' === 'string'` bound to `this` inside `example`?

Comment: It's not `call` that changes anything. It's sloppy mode that coerces the `this` value to an object (in here, a `String` object).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `call()` and setting the `this` argument to a primitive value, that primitive value is always converted to an object, so you get the string object instead of the primitive string

```
String {0: "t", 1: "e", 2: "s", 3: "t", length: 4, ...
```

The documentation for `call()` on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) states that

> ***thisArg***
>   The value of `this` provided for the call to the function.
>   Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object, **and primitive values will be converted to objects.**

So in non-strict mode the primitive string value is converted to an object, this is also specified in the [**ECMA standard, Annex C**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-C)

> ***strict mode restriction and exceptions***
>   If `this` is evaluated within strict mode code, then the `this` value is
>   not coerced to an object.
>   A this value of `null` or `undefined` is not converted to the global object and primitive values are not converted to wrapper objects.
>   The `this` value passed via a function call (including calls made using `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call`) do not coerce the passed `this` value to an object

Comment: Not a criticism of your post, but "boxed"? Why do people needlessly introduce meaningless jargon when the spec says the much more coherent "coerced to an object"?

Comment: @RobG - Who knows, it's copy/paste straight from MDN, which uses "boxed", so I continued to use that term.

Comment: It doesn't say "boxed" anymore. ;-)